# Pandas Groupby with Lambda and Algorithm

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, group-by

Given this data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import jenkspy
f = pd.DataFrame({'BreakGroup':['A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B'],
                 'Final':[1,2,3,4,5,6,10,20,30,40,50]})
    BreakGroup  Final
0         A     1
1         A     2
2         A     3
3         A     4
4         A     5
5         A     6
6         B     10
7         B     20
8         B     30
9         B     40
10        B     50
```

I'd like to use jenkspy to identify the group, based on natural breaks for 4 groups (classes), to which each value in "Final" within the group "BreakGroup" belongs.

I started out by doing this:

```
jenks=lambda x: jenkspy.jenks_breaks(f['Final'].tolist(),nb_class=4)
f['Group']=f.groupby(['BreakGroup'])['BreakGroup'].transform(jenks)
```

...which results in:

```
BreakGroup
A    [1.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 50.0]
B    [1.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 50.0]
Name: BreakGroup, dtype: object
```

The first problem here, as you may well have surmised, is that it applies the lambda function to the whole column of "Final" scores instead of just those belonging to each group in the Groupby. The second problem is that I need a column designating the correct group (class) membership, presumably by using transform instead of apply.

I then tried this:

```
jenks=lambda x: jenkspy.jenks_breaks(f['Final'].loc[f['BreakGroup']==x].tolist(),nb_class=4)
f['Group']=f.groupby(['BreakGroup'])['BreakGroup'].transform(jenks)
```

...but was promptly beaten back into submission:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

**Update:**

Here is the desired result. The "Result" column contains the upper limit of the group for the respective value from "Final" per group "BreakGroup":

```
    BreakGroup  Final   Result
0             A     1   2
1             A     2   3
2             A     3   4
3             A     4   4
4             A     5   6
5             A     6   6
6             B     10  20
7             B     20  30
8             B     30  40
9             B     40  50
10            B     50  50
```

Thanks in advance!

**My slightly modified application based on accepted solution:**

```
f.sort_values('BreakGroup',inplace=True)
f.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
jenks = lambda x: jenkspy.jenks_breaks(x['Final'].tolist(),nb_class=4)
g = f.set_index('BreakGroup')
g['Groups'] = f.groupby(['BreakGroup']).apply(jenks)
g.reset_index(inplace=True)
groups= lambda x: [gp for gp in x['Groups']]
#'final' value should be > lower and <= upper
upper = lambda x: [gp for gp in x['Groups'] if gp >= x['Final']][0] # or gp == max(x['Groups'])
lower= lambda x: [gp for gp in x['Groups'] if gp < x['Final'] or gp == min(x['Groups'])][-1]
GroupIndex= lambda x: [x['Groups'].index(gp) for gp in x['Groups'] if gp < x['Final'] or gp == min(x['Groups'])][-1]
f['Groups']=g.apply(groups, axis=1)
f['Upper'] = g.apply(upper, axis=1)
f['Lower'] = g.apply(lower, axis=1)
f['Group'] = g.apply(GroupIndex, axis=1)
f['Group']=f['Group']+1
```

This returns:

1. The list of group boundaries
2. The upper boundary pertinent to the value for "Final"
3. The lower boundary pertinent to the value for "Final"
4. The group to which the value for "Final" will belong based on logic noted in comments.

Comment: Can you post the target output?

Comment: Sure; see update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `jenks` defined as a constant in terms of `x`, your lambda variable, so it doesn't depend on what you feed it with `apply` or `transform`. Changing the definition of `jenks` to

```
jenks = lambda x: jenkspy.jenks_breaks(x['Final'].tolist(),nb_class=4)
```

gives

```
In [315]: f.groupby(['BreakGroup']).apply(jenks)
Out[315]: 
BreakGroup
A         [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 6.0]
B    [10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0]
dtype: object
```

Continuing from this redefinition,

```
g = f.set_index('BreakGroup')
g['Groups'] = f.groupby(['BreakGroup']).apply(jenks)
g.reset_index(inplace=True)
group = lambda x: [gp for gp in x['Groups'] if gp > x['Final'] or gp == max(x['Groups'])][0]
f['Result'] = g.apply(group, axis=1)
```

gives

```
In [323]: f
Out[323]: 
   BreakGroup  Final  Result
0           A      1     2.0
1           A      2     3.0
2           A      3     4.0
3           A      4     6.0
4           A      5     6.0
5           A      6     6.0
6           B     10    20.0
7           B     20    30.0
8           B     30    40.0
9           B     40    50.0
10          B     50    50.0
```

Comment: Great! By the way, I used this to get the lower limit value: group2= lambda x: [gp for gp in x['Groups'] if gp <= x['Final'] or gp == min(x['Groups'])][-1]

Comment: @DanceParty2 Since for that you're using `<=`, not `<`, you shouldn't need the `or gp == min(x['Groups'])` clause, the equivalent of which is only there in the original to avoid trying to pull an element from an empty list.

Comment: What about finding the index of the value instead of the value itself (i.e. 0 for the top row)?

Comment: Which index in the list of groups produced by `jenks`, you mean?

Comment: Yes, the index of the element in the list for the given row of g.

Comment: I can post it as a separate question if you prefer.

Comment: I think so far this falls under the same overarching umbrella as the original question – the focus of what you asked was definitely elsewhere, and that focus would be the basis on which people would find it. You'd just change the first term in the `group` list comprehension to `x['Groups'].index(gp)`, to get something like `group2index = lambda x: [x['Groups'].index(gp) for gp in x['Groups'] if gp <= x['Final']][-1]`

Comment: That did it. Thanks again. I'll post an update to how I'm using this for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are passing a series into `transform()` and not scalar as you intend for the filter condition. Consider indexing for the first value such as `x.index[0]` as all values are the same in a `groupby` series. You can even run `min(x)` or `max(x)`:

```
lambda x: jenkspy.jenks_breaks(f['Final'].loc[f['BreakGroup']==x.index[0]].tolist(), nb_class=4)

f['Group'] = f.groupby(['BreakGroup'])['BreakGroup'].transform(jenks)
```